# Sinc3 Filter in FPGA

Tags: lowpass-filter, finite-impulse-response, sinc

I working on FPGA block which requires an Sinc3 Filter for Sigma-Delta ADC coming in.
I read about it and Sinc filter, is filter with frequency response of sinc, that means its just a moving average filter right?
Frequency repsonse:

[image]

Time Domain:

[image]

so if I need Sinc3 filter implemented, which is 3rd order of Sinc filter, that means it's the first order Sinc filter cascades in serial 3 times, right?
So I Know there is an easy implementation of moving average filter using FIR filter, so to create Sinc3 filter all I need is to take the first FIR filter and cascade it 3 times in a row to create Snc3 filter, am I get it right?

Thanks

Comment: usually it is a moving-average followed by decimation. Also known as Cascaded-integrator-comb filters or CIC.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascaded_integrator%E2%80%93comb_filter

Comment: This may help you: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38377/cic-cascaded-integrator-comb-spectrum/38385#38385